# Get value from few Select in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have two MUI Select components on my page. I'm trying to set values depends on id of Select. I've checked (id === "breed-select") in console and (at first) it's true, but immediately after that it become false, and i cant understand why. Where i made a mistake? May be there is a better way to set values of two Select components? [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-bird-cebztm)

```
import React from 'react';
import './AddCatPopup.css';
import {Box, Button, FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select, TextField} from '@mui/material';
import {theme} from '../../theme';
import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';

function AddCatPopup({ breeds, isOpen, onClose, onAddCat }) {

  const breedsName = breeds.map(item => item.nameBreed);

  const colorsArray = [
    'black',
    'white',
    'grey',
    'red',
    'multicolor'
  ];

  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(0);
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState('');
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(0);
  const [breed, setBreed] = React.useState('');

  function handleChange(event) {
    const {
      target: { value, id }
    } = event;
    id === "breed-select" ? setBreed(value) : setColor(value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return(
    <section className={`popup ${isOpen && 'popup_opened'}`}>
      <div className={'popup__container'}>
        <button type="button" className={'popup__close-btn'} onClick={onClose}></button>
        <p className={'popup__title'}>Enter info about cat</p>
        <TextField sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
                   id="standard-required"
                   variant="standard"
                   label="Name"
                   required />

        <TextField sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
                   id="standard-required"
                   variant="standard"
                   label="Price"
                   required />

        <FormControl sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
                     variant="standard"
                     required>
          <InputLabel id="breed-label">Breed</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="filter-breed"
            id="breed-select"
            label="Breed"
            value={breed}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {breedsName.map((item) => (
              <MenuItem
                key={item}
                value={item}
                id="breed-select"
              >
                {item}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
                     variant="standard"
                     required>
          <InputLabel id="color-label">Color</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="filter-color"
            id="color-select"
            label="Color"
            value={color}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {colorsArray.map((item) => (
              <MenuItem
                key={item}
                value={item}
                id="color-select"
              >
                {item}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        <TextField sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
                   id="standard-required"
                   variant="standard"
                   label="Age"
                   required />

        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Button sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
                  variant="contained"
                  color={'secondary'}
                  onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Add
          </Button>
        </ThemeProvider>

      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default AddCatPopup;
```

Comment: I think you can't use same `id` for `select` and all of its inner components

Comment: @EzioMercer thank you for an answer! I've change it but it doesn't help

Comment: Can you please share minimum runnable code in public place for us to have a chance to debug your code? You can share your code on this site [codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/) or other similar site

Comment: @EzioMercer sure! [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-bird-cebztm)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that you doesn't get `id` and `value` correctly. I understand why you wrote this code, but unfortunately the event which come into `handleChange` is `MouseEvent | PointerEvent` so you could not get the correct `id` and `value`. The reason why you could choose color in this part `id === "breed-select" ? setBreed(value) : setColor(value);` you always got `id = undefined` so the `setColor` is fired always. You should use second argument of `handleChange` function. You can copypaste below code to see how does it work now

```js
import React from "react";
import "./AddCatPopup.css";
import {
  Button,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
  TextField
} from "@mui/material";
import { theme } from "./theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

function AddCatPopup({ breeds, isOpen, onClose, onAddCat }) {
  const breedsName = breeds.map((item) => item.nameBreed);

  const colorsArray = ["black", "white", "grey", "red", "multicolor"];

  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(0);
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(0);

  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("");
  const [breed, setBreed] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(event, obj) {
    const target = object.props;
    const id = target.id;
    const value = target.value;

    /breed-option/.test(id) ? setBreed(value) : setColor(value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <section className={`popup ${isOpen && "popup_opened"}`}>
      <div className={"popup__container"}>
        <button
          type="button"
          className={"popup__close-btn"}
          onClick={onClose}
        ></button>
        <p className={"popup__title"}>Enter info about cat</p>
        <TextField
          sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
          id="standard-required"
          variant="standard"
          label="Name"
          required
        />

        <TextField
          sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
          id="standard-required"
          variant="standard"
          label="Price"
          required
        />

        <FormControl sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }} variant="standard" required>
          <InputLabel id="breed-label">Breed</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="filter-breed"
            id="breed-select"
            label="Breed"
            value={breed}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {breedsName.map((item, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={item} value={item} id={'breed-option-' + index}>
                {item}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }} variant="standard" required>
          <InputLabel id="color-label">Color</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="filter-color"
            id="color-select"
            label="Color"
            value={color}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {colorsArray.map((item, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={item} value={item} id={"color-option-" + index}>
                {item}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        <TextField
          sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
          id="standard-required"
          variant="standard"
          label="Age"
          required
        />

        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Button
            sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
            variant="contained"
            color={"secondary"}
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            Add
          </Button>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default AddCatPopup;
```

Comment: [It seems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/explicitOriginalTarget) like `event.explicitOriginalTarget` works only in Firefox :(

Comment: @Rita sorry it is my mistake. I rewrite `handleChange` function. You should not use `event` to get `id` and `value`